Dart TypeError: type is not a subtype of type 'Never'
I'm mystified why the following Dart code generates a runtime error:
class Store<ID, T> {
  Store({Map<ID, T> values = const {}}) : _cache = values;

  final Map<ID, T> _cache;

  void put(ID id, T value) {
    _cache[id] = value;
  }
}

...
final foo = Store<int, Store<int, String>>();

// Runtime error inside `Store.put`:
// TypeError: 7: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'Never'
foo.put(7, Store<int, String>());

This isn't an issue if I use a Map directly like this:
final foo = Map<int, Map<int, String>>();
foo[7] = Map<int, String>());

Is there something about Dart generics I need to understand to make Store work?

"Never means that the function never returns, e.g. it ends the process or always throws an exception."  https://www.nagaraj.com.au/blog/what-is-never-in-dart
What is ID? Maybe try not specifying the ID, it might be autogenerated.

Just wanted to mention that  _cache should rather be a copy of values, for example: Store({Map<ID, T> values = const {} }) : _cache = Map.of(values); Otherwise, a user might keep a reference to values and could inadvertently change the private variable _cache.

Thank you, @DanR! I had assumed this was a copy assignment into an independent Map variable. Looks like there are Dart language semantics that I need to better understand.

I did not explicitly add it in my previous comment, but this tweak also resolves the runtime error.

If you hover over const {} in your editor it should show you Type: Map<Never, Never>. You cannot use a const map here anyways because you cannot mutate a const map. You can assign to _cache a non-constant map in the initializer list.
class Store<ID, T> {
  Store({Map<ID, T>? values}) : _cache = values ?? {};

  final Map<ID, T> _cache;

  void put(ID id, T value) {
    _cache[id] = value;
  }
}


Thank you. The requirement that default arguments be const pushed me that way, so the technique of making the argument optional and putting the default in the initializer list was the key.

I believe this was caused by const {} because it has the type Map<Never, Never>
You can try this:
class Store<ID, T> {
  Store() : _cache = {};

  final Map<ID, T> _cache;

  void put(ID id, T value) {
    _cache[id] = value;
  }
}

